# VS2008 web service code coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, web-services, code-coverage

I have written a test method for a web service in VS2008, using visual studio test framework.
Everything works fine until I enable code coverage for the web service dll in localtestrun.testrunconfig. Then, when I run the test, I get the result "Not executed". Could you give me an idea for this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the issue.
Exception was thrown: The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://localhost:59795/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of your problem is that you ran the tests in the debugger.  If you run your tests in the debugger, then code coverage is not available.  Make sure you are running the tests without the debugger attached whenever you use code coverage.